# Divide an array of numbers into the least number of arrays whose sum is less than or equal to a given number

Tags: c#, algorithm

If the array is: [ 10,10,10,20,20,30,39,50,50 ]

And maxSum is 80

The function should return a list with the least number of arrays whose sum is less than or equal to 80 (in this case a list that contains three arrays):

array1: [10,20,50] (sum=80)

array2: [10,20,50] (sum=80)

array3: [10,30,39] (sum=79)

I created an approximation algorithm, but there are cases that the following code creates more arrays than the optimal solution. Could you help me to find an algorithm that gets the optimal solution?

```
    // This is my code:
    private List<Shipment> GetShipmentsByMaxSum(double[] orderedWeights, double maxSum)
    {
        List<Shipment> result = new List<Shipment>();
        Shipment shipment = new Shipment();
        double weight = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < orderedWeights.Length; i++)
        {
            shipment.Weights.Add(orderedWeights[i]);
            weight += orderedWeights[i];

            double nextWeight = weight;
            if (i + 1 < orderedWeights.Length)
            {
                nextWeight += orderedWeights[i + 1];
            }

            if (nextWeight > maxSum || i + 1 >= orderedWeights.Length)
            {
                result.Add(shipment);
                shipment = new Shipment();
                weight = 0;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, the language is C#

Comment: This is a [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). There are many different algorithms; the general case is NP-complete.